# How to share MySQL connection between parent and children with Resque?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, resque

By default in Resque the parent process forks and the children processes create a new connection to the database.

This can work, but if you have dozens of workers, MySQL can't keep that many connections opened and starts throwing errors.

What would be the solution to have the children use the MySQL connection of their parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't a safe way to share the MySQL connection from the parent to the children.  I think you have two options to consider:

1. The easiest solution is to tune your MySQL server so that it can accept more connections (ie: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html).
2. Look at alternatives to Resque and/or designs (ie: beanstalkd, Redis, etc) that allow you to avoid creating multiple connections to the MySQL server.

Comment: I have to use a lot of connections to be able to process a lot of data as fast as possible. Changing to beanstalk or any other queuing system won't change it. Using redis for storage is a bad idea, but Resque uses it for queuing and it's perfect.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no other ways than allowing more connections?

Comment: Another options might be to use "resque-jobs-per-fork", link:  http://github.com/samgranieri/resque-jobs-per-fork. This would allow you to process multiple jobs per fork, reducing the number of concurrent connections required.  This thread might also help: http://librelist.com/browser//resque/2010/6/28/reducing-database-churn/#fd6c9fec1ed29f2f06e10ce96b578dd0.